# Get items in cart by customer id in custom adminhtml controller (M1)

Tags: magento-1.9

In my custom adminhtml controller, I need to check if a customer's cart is empty or not.

I have tried things like:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)->loadByCustomer($customer_id);
```

and variations.

I'm able to get a quote's id and even tried to get products from the cart by loading a quote by id but it always returns empty. Anyone has done something similar?

Magento 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass whole `$customer` object inside `loadByCustomer` function

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)->loadByCustomer($customer);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I have tried this and it does not make a difference. The method accepts both customer id and customer object.